MariaDB - return 1 row of each product with 2 columns, current cost and last cost



Product
Lot #
Date
Cost




Apples
1
05/24/24
30


Apples
2
05/23/24
29


Pears
3
05/22/24
28


Pears
4
05/21/24
27


Berries
5
05/20/24
26


Berries
6
05/19/24
25


Apples
7
05/18/24
24


Apples
8
05/17/24
23


Pears
9
05/16/24
22


Pears
10
05/15/24
21


Berries
11
05/14/24
20


Berries
12
05/13/24
19



Results I would like to have



Product
Lot #
Date
Cost
Last Lot #
Last Date
Last Cost




Apples
1
05/24/24
30
2
05/23/24
29


Pears
3
05/22/24
30
4
05/21/24
29


Berries
5
05/20/24
30
6
05/19/24
29



My goal is to get the latest 2 lots of any product based on the dates
Would also be nice if I could do some comparison math in a separate column but I would be happy with any help....
This is what I got so far but not sure how to account for the dates or even if this is in the right direction.
SELECT
    `productNumber`,
    `unitCost`,
    `purchaseOrder`,
    `productDesc`
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        `productNumber`,
        `unitCost`,
        `purchaseOrder`,
        `productDesc`,
        (
            @rn := IF(@prev = `productNumber`, @rn +1, 1)
        ) AS rownumb,
        @prev := `productNumber`
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            `productNumber`,
            `unitCost`,
            `purchaseOrder`,
            `productDesc`
        FROM
            `inboundDetails`
        ORDER BY
            `productNumber`
        DESC
            ,
            `unitCost`
    ) AS sortedlist
JOIN(
SELECT
    @prev := NULL,
    @rn := 0
) AS vars
) AS groupedlist
WHERE
    rownumb <= 2
ORDER BY
    `productNumber`
DESC
    ,
    `unitCost`


your sample result only has one row per product, not 2 rows. Which is it?

Are you using MySQL 8.x? Then you should be able to use window functions for this.

I would like to return 1 row with additional columns containing the "Last" data

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.1.16

Not the client version, the database server version. SELECT VERSION()

Sorry, 10.6.17-MariaDB-cll-lve

Window functions were added in 10.2, so you can use them.

what is "current cost", what determines which row for a product is "current"? what determines which row for a product is "last"?

Why is the last date for Apples 5/23 instead of 5/24? Do you mean previous date?

Use the LAG() window function to get the previous row by date.

I've edited the title and tags for this question. Please be aware that MariaDB and MySQL are not the same database. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed a lot over the years, and we can no longer assume they are compatible. You should be clear which one you use when you ask questions.

Let me clarify what my goal is.
I would like to compare the latest cost to the previous cost so I can see spikes in cost.
So for example, Apples I would like Like to see the top 2 rows because they are the 2 newest lots of apples. same thing for the rest of the items.
The results could be 2 rows per item but prefer to have the records returned on a single line like the example above. Adding additional columns to hold the vales of the previous lot and cost.
Thank you for all your help. I just cant figure it out.
Neither option.

You can use window function row_number() to detect last and previous rows.
Then pivot by lead(...) function.
See example



Product
LotN
Date
Cost




Apples
1
2024-05-24
30


Apples
2
2024-05-23
29


Pears
3
2024-05-22
28


Pears
4
2024-05-21
27


Berries
5
2024-05-20
26


Berries
6
2024-05-19
25


Apples
7
2024-05-18
24


Apples
8
2024-05-17
23


Pears
9
2024-05-16
22


Pears
10
2024-05-15
21


Berries
11
2024-05-14
20


Berries
12
2024-05-13
19


Banana
13
2024-05-13
9



select Product, LotN lastLotN,Date LastDate,Cost LastCost, rn
  ,prevLotN,prevDate,prevCost
from(    
select *
  ,lead(LotN)over(partition by Product order by date desc) prevLotN
  ,lead(Date)over(partition by Product order by date desc) prevDate
  ,lead(Cost)over(partition by Product order by date desc) prevCost
  ,row_number()over(partition by Product order by date desc)rn
from inboundDetails
)a
where rn=1




Product
lastLotN
LastDate
LastCost
rn
prevLotN
prevDate
prevCost




Apples
1
2024-05-24
30
1
2
2024-05-23
29


Banana
13
2024-05-13
9
1
null
null
null


Berries
5
2024-05-20
26
1
6
2024-05-19
25


Pears
3
2024-05-22
28
1
4
2024-05-21
27



fiddle
